# Replace every color except a specific one in Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

Let's say I have a PNG image with some random colors in it, like this one:

[image: Like this one.]

The goal is to make every color in the image EXCEPT a specific color (like #FCFF00) with pure black (#000000). So for example, if I gave the code the above image, it would replace it with this:

[image: It would replace it with this?]

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the [`+opaque`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#opaque) option.

```
convert YiCYA.png -fill black +opaque '#FC00FF' output.png
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: ASIDE: If the color you want to preserve is not just one exact color, but also nearly the same, then add -fuzz XX% where XX is how close of colors you want expressed as percent. Add it before -fill. Also if your image is not RGB (e.g. CMYK), then you need to convert to sRGB first.